# Find common entities in 2 seperate entity collections

Tags: c#, linq, collections, entities

I have two collections, Customer, and Email. Customer has a Customer.Email field and the Email entity has an Email.From field. I need to get all the entities from the Email collection where Customer.Email equals Email.From but I need it to return the email entity not just the Email.From field.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Email> result =  emails.Where(p => customers.Any(q => q.Email == p.From)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! My experience with link amounts to about 3 hours :/ This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to return the Customer Entity that it matched with as well? Or even just the Customer.Id because I need to create a relationship between the two

Comment: Nevermind. var result = customerCollection.Where(p => email.From == p.Email);

Answer (score 1):

This will effect efficiency because for each entry in email it will have to match each entry in Customer till it finds correct entry.

Still

```
var results = Emails.Where(e => e.From == customers.Select (c => c.Email));
```

**OR**

```
var results = Emails.Where(e => Customers.Any(c => c.Email == e.From));
```